# "supervisory" software for school rooms

Tags: vnc, remote-management, remote-desktop

In a schoolroom there are 15 machines + 1 the teacher's PC. All have ex.: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Are there any softwares that can be used on the teachers machine that can "audit" the students 15 PC? Things needed: 

 - teacher must see the students "display" from his PC.
 - teacher could show 1 students "display" to all of the other students or his own monitor.
 - extra: teacher could "control" the students machine remotely (ex.: to show the student the good solution for a given exercise)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[iTALC](http://italc.sourceforge.net/home.php) lets you monitor and control several computers in a classroom environment. It might do what you need. I'm not sure about showing a student's screen on all others, though.

There is also [LanSchool](http://www.lanschool.com/), [Nettop](http://www.netop.com/products/education.htm), and [NetSupport Assist](http://www.netsupportassist.com/), all of which are commercial solutions.

If none of those are what you're looking for, you might want to take a look at [Wikipedia's Comparison of Remote Desktop Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software).

Comment: i Accepted iTALC, but are there any better softwares? :) just being curious :)

Answer (score 1):

Although this could be achieved by utilizing native *Xorg* client-server structure, I believe you are looking for an easy-to-setup software. That's what [VNC software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC) is meant for.

Basically, in your case, all the students' computers would have to be running VNC servers in order for the teacher to see and interact with their desktops. And on the other side, the teacher's computer would also need to run a server to show thing to the students, but his server must be configured differently - not to allow students to interfere with teacher's desktop.

You may find some examples of popular VNC software in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VNC), but the best way to get a well-supported implementation is to search your distro's documentation.

Comment: Ubuntu includes by default the packages vino, a VNC server, and vinagre, a VNC client. vino can be configured within a GNOME GUI interface; it has to be explicitly set to allow remote connections, optionally with a password. Finding the config file, and editing it on each workstation via a shell script, might be best, but if there are only a small number of student computers, it may be easier to go from computer to computer and set it by hand.